# Need help in definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I put a red mark on the (Subtraction) because when I solve it it comes out as (Addition) not (Subtraction) and the final result show up as 2 not 1 which is wrong.

Help me know my mistake please :/

Thanks in advance <3

[image]

Comment: Because the fundamental theorem of calculus states $\int_a^b g(x)\,dx = G(b) \color{red}{-} G(a)$, where $G'(x) = g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought it's (Addition) that's explain it all!!! .. thanks again, a true life saver <3 and sorry for your time.